# How to retrive raw socket FD from boost ip::tcp::socket type?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost

1) How can i get raw socket fd from boost ip::tcp::socket type ??

2) Can i able to read from ip::tcp::socket type of boost library and write through normal send(fd...) system call ? Is that feasible. Can some one help me..

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Suyambu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get the socket fd from `ip::tcp::socket::native()`.

> Get the native socket representation.
>
> native_type native();
>
> This function may be used to obtain the underlying representation of the socket. This is intended to allow access to native socket functionality that is not otherwise provided.

I would imagine you can read through this class and write through `send` since the buffers should be segregated but you'll need to test it.